# What are these numbers that come after the three digit http status code?

Tags: http

```
[13/Jun/2021 10:15:21] "GET /admin/r/18/2/ HTTP/1.1" 500 **112909**
[13/Jun/2021 10:21:47] "GET /__debug__/render_panel/? 
store_id=390e09a41aa149b6bed1c05d0451e555&panel_id=RequestPanel HTTP/1.1" 200 **2080**
[13/Jun/2021 10:24:22] "GET /__debug__/render_panel/? 
store_id=390e09a41aa149b6bed1c05d0451e555&panel_id=SQLPanel HTTP/1.1" 200 **35097**
[13/Jun/2021 10:25:01] "POST /__debug__/sql_explain/ HTTP/1.1" 200 **2008**
```

What are these **double starred** (by me) numbers *after* the three digit status code? I can't find an explanation. I don't even know what they are called, so I don't know how to look them up. Thanks.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html.  "The last entry indicates the size of the object returned to the client, not including the response headers. If no content was returned to the client, this value will be `-`."  (I am just assuming that this is an Apache logfile, since it looks like one, but it'd be nice if you had said so.)

Comment: I think this would be better for serverfault.SE or similar; it isn't a programming issue.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thanks. This seems to be what I was looking for. And it is wsgi/gunicorn, not apache. Finally, moving it is fine, but should I do that, or is that only for moderators? But since the question has been answered, you could just put your comment in an answer for me to accept and just close it.

Comment: There is a way for moderators to migrate questions, but for questions that haven't yet received an official answer, it's usually more efficient if the asker just deletes it themselves and reposts on the other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a Common Log Format file as used by many web servers.  You can find [documentation of this format on Apache's website](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html), among other places:

> The last entry indicates the size of the object returned to the client, not including the response headers. If no content was returned to the client, this value will be "-".

So generally, this is the number of bytes that the server sent in response to the request.

Comment: Despite your advice about how to move, someone has come along and shut this question down. I am trying to see if I can at least give you credit as promised. Thanks.